# Could not find installable ISAM while filling data in DataSet

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, excel

I know this question is repeated but problem with me is I have tried almost all the link for solution and I didnt get the success. So here is the scenario: 
I have a input type = file & when I click on submit button, it POST the file.

here is the code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase excel_File)
{
  if (excel_File != null)
  {
    //Save the uploaded file to the disc.
    string saved_FileName = Path.Combine(@ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["excel_file_storage_path"] + excel_File.FileName); // Taking file upload location from web.config
    excel_File.SaveAs(saved_FileName);
    var connectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES", saved_FileName);
    //Fill the dataset with information from the Sheet1 worksheet.
    var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", connectionString);
    var ds = new DataSet();
    adapter.Fill(ds);  // I get error here.
    DataTable data = ds.Tables[0];
    var obj_Table = new DataTable("Sample_Upload_Expense");
    obj_Table.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(Int16));
    obj_Table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
      obj_Table.Rows.Add(data.Rows[i].Field<double>("Id"), data.Rows[i].Field<string>("Name"));
    }
    var arrParam = new List<SqlParameter>();
    var para = new SqlParameter();
    para.ParameterName = "@RowList";
    para.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Structured;
    para.Value = obj_Table;
    var pNumRowsChanged = new SqlParameter("@NumRowsChanged", SqlDbType.Int);
    pNumRowsChanged.Value = 0;
    arrParam.Add(para);
    arrParam.Add(pNumRowsChanged);
    string proc = "SPInsertExpense";
    int no = DataProvider.ProcRetunAffectedRows(proc, arrParam);
    return View();
}
```

Help me. I am stuck from 2 days and I am not able to find the solution.

file path in web.config:

```
<appSettings>
<add key="excel_file_storage_path" value="D:\webapps\uploads\UploadedExcelDocuments\" />
</appSettings>
```

**I have tried:**

1. I installed 2007 Office System Driver - Data Connectivity Components to solve if there is any connectivity issue but it doesnt work.
2. Tried putting single quotes around the data source.
3. I put static path in connection string but that also dont work.
4. Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214527/could-not-find-installable-isam), though it is not related with my issue.

Comment: @pnuts okies, then i m giving u examples which kinda soln i tried & didnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally it worked. I tried [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/509179/Read-Excel-File-into-DataSet-in-ASP-NET-Using-Csha), & it worked. Actuality in connection string, it needs two **;** (semicolons) at the end. So my **connectionString** must be like follow:

```
var connectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;';", saved_FileName);
```